# ping, disk and services check

Tags: powershell

I have been asked to come up with a PowerShell script to do the following:

1. Ping a list of servers and send an email if the ping is unsuccessful
2. If the ping is successful, check the disk space to make sure it has more than 500MB free.  If under this threshold, email an alert
3. To check if the IISADMIN and CCMEXEC services are running, and again email an alert if they are not.

I have come up with the below code but it doesn't appear to be working correctly and need another pair of eyes on it to help me out.

```psh
$rtn = $null
$Computer = $null
$EmailRecipient = "xxx@xxx.com","xxx@xxx.com"

# Lookup all computers from AD starting with XXXXX
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -Like "XXXXX*"} | select -ExpandProperty name

# Ping each computer
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $computer.toUpper() -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet

    IF ($rtn -match 'False') {
        # Send email to say computer unreachable
        #write-host $computer "unreachable"
        Send-MailMessage -From "ICT DESKTOP ALERTS<XXX@XXX.co.uk>" -To $EmailRecipient -Subject "DP Checker - Unreachable - $Computer" -Smtpserver emailrelay
    }
}

IF ($rtn -match 'True') {
    {
        foreach ( $computer in $computers ) {
            get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where-object { $_.FreeSpace -lt 500MB } | foreach-object {
                Send-MailMessage -From "xxx@xxx.com<xxx@xxx.com>" -To $EmailRecipient -Subject "DP Checker - Low HDD space - $Computer" -Smtpserver emailrelay
            }
        }
    }
    {
        IF ($IIS.State -ne 'Running') {
            Send-MailMessage -From "xxx@xxx.com<xxx@xxx.com>" -To $EmailRecipient -Subject "DP Checker - Service - IIS - Not Running - $Computer" -Smtpserver emailrelay
        }
    }
    {
        IF ($SMS.State -ne 'Running') {
            Send-MailMessage -From "xxx@xxx.com<xxx@xxx.com>" -To $EmailRecipient -Subject "DP Checker - Service - SMS - Not Running - $Computer" -Smtpserver emailrelay
        }
    }
}

# Check if IIS and SMS services are running
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $IIS = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'IISADMIN'" -ComputerName $computer -erroraction silentlycontinue
    $SMS = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'ccmexec'" -ComputerName $computer -erroraction silentlycontinue
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working correctly".  That's like taking your car to a mechanic and just telling him "It needs fixed.".

Comment: What do you mean by not working? It would be easier if you showed us what was happeneing

Comment: (Remove the email in line 17 to prevent spam).

Comment: Apologies. The ping part works OK, but the disk check part doesn't seem to work at all.  I believe the IF ($rtn -match 'True') section downwards should be within the same bracketed area as that above it, but when I try that it doesn't work either.

Comment: Start by changing `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to `-ErrorAction Continue` and see what you get.

Comment: Why the second and third `foreach` after `$rtn -match 'True'`? I feel that might be a source of problems. YOu are already in the loop and you only want to check that current computer. Not the would group again.

Comment: Also you are reacting to the state of `$IIS` and `$SMS` before they are populated which will lead to odd results.

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your script is broken. You first ping all computers. After that you run the disk check on *all* computers only if the connection to the *last* computer was successful *and* try to determine the states of the services when you haven't actually queried their state. *Then* you run the actual service checks (again on *all* computers) unconditionally.

Change your logic to something like this:

```psh
ForEach ($computer in $computers) {
  $rtn = Test-Connection -CN $computer -Count 1 -BufferSize 16 -Quiet

  if (-not $rtn) {
    # ping failed
    Send-MailMessage ...
  } else {
    # ping succeeded
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $computer |
      ? { $_.FreeSpace -lt 500MB } |
      % { Send-MailMessage ... }

    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Computer $computer -Filter "Name='IISADMIN'" |
      ? { $_.State -ne 'Running' } |
      % { Send-MailMessage ... }
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -Computer $computer -Filter "Name='ccmexec'" |
      ? { $_.State -ne 'Running' } |
      % { Send-MailMessage ... }
  }
}
```